# How to carry out mediated moderation with three groups

Tags: r, interaction, mediation

I have the results of an experiment that is set up this way: I'm testing the effects of a human vs non-human stimulus on the dependent variable, an effect which is mediated by a mediator. Simple enough.

However, I also want to see how gender can moderate this effect. Since gender only applies to the human stimulus, I have three conditions, human-male, human-female, and non-human.

I want to see how the human groups as a whole compares to the non-human group in terms of the mediator and then the dependent variable. I then want to see how gender might moderate this effect. Is this a valid set-up?

Also, if possible, what packages might I use to accomplish this analysis on R?